# "Should" as formal IF

Tags: formality, should

Can a phrase starting with "if" always be replaced with a phrase with a phrase starting with SHOULD?  It doesn't seem like we can make a direct substitution.  For example, we say

> *If* he *askED* you to move to Italy, would you do it?

But

> *Should* he *ask* you to move to Italy, would you do it?

Why is this, and what is the rule for the substitution?

Comment: It's not informal; it's just different.  They are different ways to express the same idea.  Another way would be to say, "Were he to ask you to move to Italy, would you do it?"  These ways don't nuance different meanings; they mean exactly the same thing.  Any answer as to "why" would be opinion-based.  Which is used is personal preference, and maybe somewhat geographically influenced, but none of them are weird in any locale.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I need concrete answers. "It is THIS one or THAT one. Because..." Like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ***Should** you do it?* asks if it's the *right* thing to do (regardless of whether you actually do it or not), whereas ***Would** you do it?* asks if you *will* do it (regardless of whether it's a wise/honourable thing to do). This is basic English, and the matter of using past tense ***asked*** (totally ungrammatical in OP's context) is even more basic.

Comment: Related question, [If/should… INVERSION FORM](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238707/if-should-inversion-form).

Comment: @JonatanCarminati Watch your language.

Comment: @Rathony your latest comment was uncalled-for.

Comment: @Jonatan: You are quite right - I didn't read the question properly, because I was making a cup of tea at the time. I initially assumed you were asking about *should/would you do it*. But I just got back in time to edit the comment and add the bit about ***asked***. I am frankly astonished that someone with your apparent level of competence in English could ask such a question, and I genuinely would be interested to know *why* the "correct" form isn't obvious to you. But that's an ELL issue, not really relevant to ELU, imho.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - It seems odd to say both are right when the second one is *clearly* ungrammatical...

Comment: @ChrisSunami THANK YOU, Chris. That's the only comment  I needed. So... the first option is the correct one. SHOULD doesn't follow the same grammatical structure as IF, right?
So, in conditional scales:
a) [If + present , will] = [SHOULD + present , will]

b) If + past simple , would = [should + present , would]
am I correct? 

and can we use "SHOULD" for the third conditional? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Belay that last point - I now realise your problem is simply that you haven't recognized the subjunctive for what it is. It may also be worth mentioning that *a very long time ago* it was reasonable to treat ***should*** and ***if*** as interchangeable (KJV [if he ask a fish, will he for a fish give him a serpent?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+he+ask+a+fish%2C+will+he+for+a+fish+give+him+a+serpent%22), but you can't do that in modern English.

Comment: I think the way your question is phrased is making it easy to misinterpret.  You're actually wondering how it is that "should" can be interchanged with "if" given that it can't be used as an exact replacement...

Comment: @ChrisSunami: Precisely. But I think it's also worth pointing out that in my example above, preceding text clearly shows that ***ask*** is a "reduced" form of ***shall ask*** (at the time, a credible "subjunctive" alternative to ***should ask***).

Comment: @ChrisSunami yeah, it could be. But this is an entrance exam task itself. I mean... it's requested BY PROFESSIONALS that we should replace a conditional preposition with a phrase beginning with "SHOULD"

Comment: @JonatanCarminati I made some edits to highlight your question as I now understand it.  Please feel free to revert if this misrepresents your actual intentions.

Comment: @JonatanCarminati Did you read [the answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238707/if-should-inversion-form/238726#238726) in the related question I posted?

Comment: @JonatanCarminati : Here is a link to *Cambridge Dictionaries'* explanation of using "should" for "if" in conditional clauses that invert the subject and verb such as these do: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as .  Should you have any questions, please leave another comment.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is correct, the second not. The verb form, *should ask* is subjunctive and expresses a hypothetical situation that has not yet happened.

The verb form *should asked* is not a standard form. If you were describing a hypothetical referring to a time already passed, you could say

> *Should he have asked you ...*
>
> or
>
> *If he had asked you ...*

But note that these describe something that did not happen.

Comment: So, the answer is "should he ask you to move to Italy, would you do it?", right? I thought the same.

Comment: The original question seems to have been edited in a way that makes this answer incorrect / irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Modal verbs require verb complements in the infinitive form:

> Should he **ask** ...
>   He should **ask** ...

*Should SUBJ asked* is ungrammatical.

*Asked* could occur, however, if the complement of the modal is auxiliary *BE* or *HAVE* taking *asked* as ***its*** complement:

> Should he **be asked**, he will respond ...
>   Should he **have asked**, he would have been told ...

The last one, however, is clumsy; with an irrealis we'd usually say

> **Had** he **asked**, he would have been told ...