# should you have (conditionals)

Tags: conditionals

> If you had wanted to cancel the reservation, you would not have gotten a full refund.
>
> Should you have wanted to cancel the reservation, you would not have gotten a full refund.

I can't decide if this second sentence is possible, and if so, what it is.

Is it a third conditional sentence?

Is it possible to make this construction?

Does it have the same meaning as the first sentence?

Comment: I would say: *If you* ***had*** *wanted to cancel the reservation, you* ***should*** *not have gotten a full refund.* However, although grammatical, I should note that this sentence doesn't actually make sense. If you got a full refund then you *did* cancel the reservation. So, I would drop the **not**.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Should" as formal IF](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300077/should-as-formal-if)

Comment: Is it supposed to make any difference to this question whether it's *If you had **wanted to** cancel...* as opposed to *If you had **cancelled...*** ?

Comment: But 'should' can replace the 'if' part in conditionals in certain circumstances. I can say for example, 'should you have a question, please raise your hand.' Or at least I believe this is correct.

Comment: I know the structure is odd, but is it possible?

Comment: It seems fine. And, yes, the two are equivalent in meaning. The latter example has "if" omitted and subject-auxiliary inversion. Compare also, "Had you wanted to cancel ..."

Comment: This was my thought. If I said,  'I should have eaten that cake', it seems to indicate a past regret which is similar to the use of the third conditional. So if I invert them, the meaning seems similar. 'should I have eaten the cake, I would not feel regret now.' admittedly, it does sound odd.

Comment: Claire - there is no meaningful connection between the statement *I should have done that* and the conditional subjunctive clause *Should I have done that...* in terms of possible implications  of "regret" (or anything else, for that matter). The usages are completely unconnected in terms of semantics.

Answer (score 0):

While it is grammatically correct, the addition of the extra layer of [conditional complexity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238707/if-should-inversion-form) conveys the diplomatic too-carefully-chosen word choice of high society or just someone acting holier-than-thou. If that's not what you're going for, I'd stick to number 1.