# Should danger approach

Tags: meaning-in-context, subject-verb-inversion, should

Should danger approach either its nest or the crocodile nest, the bird would emit warning cries.

A. What is the grammatical name for this expression?
B. What is its function?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/467026/191178

Comment: It's the subjunctive — for counterfactual conditions. It means the same as: *If danger were to approach . . .*